# Processing of heterogeneous documents XML in Hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop, mahout

I work with hadoop 1.1.1. as I process XML documents, I use `XmlInputFormat` existing in **MAHOUT**. It is plain that `START_TAG` and `END_TAG` should be assigned. This kind of process is suitable for these kind of data(**homogeneous**):

```
<lib>
    <book> ... </book>
    <book> ... </book>
    <book> ... </book>
    ...
</lib>
```

According to what I said, I assign `START_TAG=<book>` and `END_TAG=</book>`.
if the documents or data are in the form of below (**heterogeneous***):

**Document 1:**

```
<lib>
    <book> ... </book>
    <article> ... </article>
    <journal> ... </journal>
    <www> ... </www>
    ...
</lib>
```

AND **Document 2:**

```
<Doc>
    <paper> ... </paper>
    <white_paper> ... </white_paper>
    <report> ... </report>
    <booklet> ... </booklet>
    ...
</Doc>
```

How can I assign `START_TAG` and `END_TAG`?
How this kind of data can be processed in hadoop?

Thanks a lot

Comment: for doc1 and doc2 is lib and doc the XML document root element, or are there multiple instances of these elements that make up the document?

Comment: My documents are formed by multiple instances. You can find it in the web site below :[link](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/niagara/data/)

Comment: Do the two (threee, four?) different document types have their types encoded into the filename (doc1.lib.xml and doc2.doc.xml), or are they intermixed in the same xml document?

Comment: I want **classification** a series of different xml documents in hadoop. I have 1000 xml documents, Which are composed of 4 classes. How this kind of data can be processed in hadoop? while the `XmlInputFormat` have one `start_tag` and one `end_tag`!!!

Answer (score 0):

A global ontology can be used to dynamically define the start and end tags used by different document types.  Developing a global ontology when dealing with heterogeneous systems should always be a priority when those systems will be integrated.